# PyQt Subclassing QTcpServer and QTcpSocket

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qtcpsocket, qtcpserver

I am trying to implement a custom TCP Socket and Server using the
`PyQt5.QtNetwork.QTcpSocket` and `PyQt5.QtNetwork.QTcpServer` as baseclasses. The [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-5/PySide2/QtNetwork/QTcpServer.html#PySide2.QtNetwork.PySide2.QtNetwork.QTcpServer.nextPendingConnection)
states one has to override `QTcpServer.incomingConnection` to return
custom Socket objects. This seems to work fine in principle, but I keep stumbling over some odd behavior. Whenn calling `QTcpServer.nextPendingConnection`, the method does indeed seem to return the expected `MyNewSocket` instance, however when one accesses any attribute or method of the new socket, the interpreter first returns said attribute / method, but then goes on to inform you that
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'anyAttribute'` which I can find no reasonable explanation for so far.
Here is a MWE that shows the behavior. I am using `PyQt5` v5.15.

`tcpmodule.py`:

```py
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QTcpSockert, QTcpServer

class MyNewSocket(QTcpSocket):
    """do some additional stuff to the
       original QTcpSocket stuff"""
    pass

class MyNewServer(QTcpServer):
    def incomingConnection(self, handle):
        """Returns a MyNewSocket instance instead of
           original QTcpSocket instance"""
        socket = MyNewSocket(self)
        socket.setSocketDescriptor(handle)
        self.addPendingConnection(socket)
        self.newConnection.emit()
```

`server.py`

```py
from tcpmodule import MyNewServer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress

app = QApplication([])
win = QMainWindow()
server = MyNewServer(win)
server.listen(QHostAddress.SpecialAddress.LocalHost, 9999)

def newConnection():
    socket = server.nextPendingConnection()
    print("Acces any Attribute ", socket.connected)
    print("Socket is ", socket, " Socket Type is", type(socket))

server.newConnection.connect(newConnection)

win.show()
app.exec()
```

`client.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from tcpmodule import MyNewSocket
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtNetwork import QHostAddress

app = QApplication([])
win = QMainWindow()

socket = MyNewSocket(win)
socket.connectToHost(QHostAddress.SpecialAddress.LocalHost, 9999)

def connected():
    socket.write(b"Hello, World!")

socket.connected.connect(connected)

win.show()
app.exec()
```

After running the `server.py` and subsequent `client.py` connection,
I get the following output

```bash
Acces any Attribute  <bound PYQT_SIGNAL connected of MyNewSocket object at 0x7f4be28597e0>                                                                                        
Socket is  <tcpmodule.MyNewSocket object at 0x7f4be28597e0>  Socket Type is <class 'tcpmodule.MyNewSocket'>                                                                     
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                       
  File "./server.py", line 13, in newConnection        
    print("Acces any Attribute ", socket.connected)                                      
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'connected'
```

Can anyone please tell me what is going on?!

Comment: As far as I can understand from the sources, you don't need to emit `newConnection`. Try removing it and see if it works as expected.

Comment: well, that was an unexpectedly easy solution. I did not catch that because the documentation states `The base implementation creates a QTcpSocket , sets the socket descriptor and then stores the QTcpSocket in an internal list of pending connections. Finally newConnection() is emitted.` So a natrual assumption would be to also emit newConnection... Thanks for the fast help anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation, it seems that [`incomingConnection()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#incomingConnection) emits the `newConnection()` signal, but, in fact it does not.

By looking at the [sources](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network/socket/qtcpserver.cpp?h=5.15#n602), we see that it just creates the socket, sets its descriptor and appends it to the pending connections:

```cpp
void QTcpServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
#if defined (QTCPSERVER_DEBUG)
    qDebug("QTcpServer::incomingConnection(%i)", socketDescriptor);
#endif

    QTcpSocket *socket = new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    addPendingConnection(socket);
}
```

In fact, the signal is only emitted by the private function [`readNotification()`](https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/network/socket/qtcpserver.cpp?h=5.15#n195), which calls `incomingConnection()` *and* finally emits the signal.

So, you don't have to emit it on your own, because in that case the second time you call `nextPendingConnection()` you'll get a `nullptr` (`None`) as the socket has been already read in the previous call, and there are no more connections available.